# Move multiples files into different versions of one file

Tags: versioning, word, merge

I have a lot of Word files that are actually different versions of the same document. I'd like to save these files as one file using versioning in SharePoint 2010.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: If you apply versioning it will work with later documents, I don't think there is a way to create versions OOB.. But nothing is impossible when it comes to coding :)